# How to get page source?

Tags: c#, http

How to get page source (ex: html, aspx, php) in C#?

like this:

```
<head>

<title>Ask a Question - Stack Overflow</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
```

Comment: Try to be a little bit more clearer in what you want to achieve

Comment: By requesting it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to create a WebClient object and call its [DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method, although if you need anything other than a simple request/response, you may have to use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to craft your request.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what's being asked, but don't you just want to open a tcp connection to the correct port (typically 80) of the webserver, write a 'POST' of the correct variety and then read the response data?

If so, look for http helper classes/libraries that are available in C#

Answer (score 0):

you can use httpwebrequest class or webclient class, its in system.net namespace.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
UTF8Encoding encoding1 = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] downloadDataInBytes = client.DownloadData("http://negaweblog.wordpress.com");
string websitesource = encoding1.GetString(downloadDataInBytes);
```